# Unable to decrypt an encrypted Http Post request from an android app

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, reverse-engineering

Trying to test an app and get intercepted http post login of the app, but unfortunately the http body request was encrypted. since apparently the encryption was done on the client side it is clear enough to retrieve the encryption key and the algorithm scheme, I then reversed the app and I suspected that the following code behind the encryption:

```
import a.a;
import android.util.Base64;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class b {

    /* renamed from: a reason: collision with root package name */
    private static volatile b f4799a;

    /* renamed from: b reason: collision with root package name */
    private byte[] f4800b = null;

    /* renamed from: c reason: collision with root package name */
    private String f4801c;

    private b() {
        try {
            this.f4801c = a.a(new byte[]{97, 110, 100, 95, 50, 51, 116, 107, 108, 35, 95, 97, 105, 116, 33}, new byte[]{75, 24, 109, 27, -24, -51, 22, -58, -44, -74, 21, 91, -88, 48, -52, -63, 69, -67, 71, 17, 116, 77, 70, -94, 41, 121, 20, 120, 8, 121, 33, 77});
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.f4800b = e(this.f4801c);
    }

    public static b a() {
        if (f4799a == null) {
            synchronized (b.class) {
                if (f4799a == null) {
                    f4799a = new b();
                }
            }
        }
        return f4799a;
    }

    private final String c(String str) {
        try {
            Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            instance.init(2, new SecretKeySpec(this.f4800b, "DESede"));
            return a(instance.doFinal(new a().a(str)));
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private final String d(String str) {
        try {
            Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            instance.init(1, new SecretKeySpec(this.f4800b, "DESede"));
            try {
                return Base64.encodeToString(instance.doFinal(str.getBytes()), 0);
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            } catch (BadPaddingException e3) {
                e3.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e4) {
            e4.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e5) {
            e5.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e6) {
            e6.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final byte[] e(String str) {
        try {
            return MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String b(String str) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(str);
        sb.append(b());
        return d(sb.toString());
    }

    private String b() {
        int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(999999);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("|");
        sb.append(nextInt);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String a(String str) {
        return c(str).split(Pattern.quote("|"))[0];
    }

    public b(String str) {
        this.f4800b = e(str);
    }

    private final String a(byte[] bArr) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b2 : bArr) {
            stringBuffer.append((char) b2);
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

honestly, I didnt understand how to find the encryption key and how this code produces http post request body like below:

```
{
"UserName":"N67a2TEuY6/+6ev2csIlcUnh0f844m+a\n",
"Password":"t1h6/ATZ26VA8nS+fcnvkgtyapIPArT7\n"
}
```

*I would appreciate your help.
thanks*

Comment: What's your question? It's also a bit hard to help if all you have is obfuscated code.

Comment: @Nicolas, yeah it is heavily obfuscated, the app is making http request but its body was encrypted and I thought this code was behind it but I hardly to understand it.